# How to save using localStorage on each item and not for all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, local-storage

I have a problem with `localStorage` that will remember all saves even if one section is closed but the other is suppose to remain. Example: There's two banners on a page. If one person clicks to close a banner, it will close that banner but will also remember that the other banner has been closed as well.

Code:

```
<section class="alert-notice-contain status-alerts">

<div id ="1561524897" class="type-notice relative">
    <div class="close-notice-alert"></div>
    <div class="status-contain">
        <div class="status-msg">
            <p>This is a test. This is a long test.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id ="1561524873" class="type-notice relative">
    <div class="close-notice-alert"></div>
    <div class="status-contain">
        <div class="status-msg">
            <p>This is notice 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script> // JS code (inline to get the dynamic #ID
( function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
            // Status
if(localStorage.getItem('isHide'))
$('#1561524897').hide();
$('#1561524897 .close-notice-alert').click(function(){
$('#1561524897').hide();localStorage.setItem('isHide',true);
});
} );
} ( jQuery ) );
</script>

<script>
    ( function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
            // Status
if(localStorage.getItem('isHide'))
$('#1561524873').hide();
$('#1561524873 .close-notice-alert').click(function(){
$('#1561524873').hide(); localStorage.setItem('isHide',true);});
} );
} ( jQuery ) );
</script>

</section>
```

Comment: Use an object (and `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`) to store the visibility of the banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store with the id instead of simply set the same variable 'isHide' to true or not.
For example, set to store: `localStorage.setItem('isHide-1561524897', true);` 
and read it: `localStorage.getItem('isHide-1561524897');`

Comment: Yep. literally the answer came to me in dream after I submitted the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to store in localstorage.
JSON.stringify() to convert your object to string form and JSON.parse() to convert string to object form after getting from localstorage.
For ex.

```
obj = { visibility : 'hidden' }

// set the localstorage
localstorage.setItem('isHide', JSON.stringify(obj));

// get the localstorage
let storageValue = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('isHide'));
// use storageValue accordingly
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem, because there's still only one state for all elements.